# Datatranformation mlogit models

Tags: r, regression, data-management, mlogit

I want to run a multinomial model with season as a random factor. A lot of sources say mlogit models are the best option. However, I am very much confused by how I should format my data frame.

My goal is to make a model such as: Ecology = Group + Period + Method with hunting season as random factor.

For now, my data is in the wide format I guess. (Ecology is the response variable)

```
quota   pop_estimate    Ecology     Group   Period  method  season
440         2340        kitten   Family Pack   5      DD     11_12
440         2340      adult male    Solo       4      DD     11_12
```

Summarised my data looks like

```
 quota      pop_estimate          Ecology2           Group      Period  method      season   
 Min.   :314   Min.   :1865   1y female   :271   Family Pack: 263   1:348   DD:1624   11_12:336  
 1st Qu.:440   1st Qu.:2340   1y male     :315   Solo       :1655   2:221   HD: 294   12_13:337  
 Median :440   Median :2490   2y female   :123                      3:373             13_14:422  
 Mean   :471   Mean   :2447   2y male     :256                      4:425             14_15:400  
 3rd Qu.:503   3rd Qu.:2700   adult female:273                      5:312             17_18:275  
 Max.   :589   Max.   :2740   adult male  :279                      6:239             20_21:148  
                              kitten      :401
```

How should I format my data in order to be able to use the mlogit command? I do not understand the explanation in the vignette (I am not experienced at all with this kind of models)...

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Also appears to have multiple lines per pack (i.e. long format) unless only "kitten" is recorded when a "Family Pack" was observed. The "season" variable appears to an ordered recording of yearly intervals and the "period" appears to either be bimontly or montly observations, which would likewise be ordered. I'm wondering if you need statistical advice within your domain of study?

Comment: Yes, there are indeed multiple lines per pack (it actually depicts a kind of tracking method). Period (each period is two weeks) and season are indeed ordered. Does this imply that I cannot use mlogit models? normal multinomial models do a great job, but I want to add hunting season as a random factor. Unfortunately this does not seems to be as straightforward as a binomial model with random factors...

Comment: I think it means your data is in long format. Hard to say what "adding hunting season" really means since there is no description of what those values are attached to in the real world. With no data or code and no clear description of what these variable mean I think this Q ought to be deleted here and re-posed on https://stats.stackexchange.com